# Using the Java Testcontainers library in Cloud Build

Tags: java, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, testcontainers

I'm trying to use the Java Testcontainers library to start up a PostgreSQL database docker during my unit tests. This works locally, but fails when I try to deploy it on Cloud Build. The following is my cloudbuild.yml file:

```
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    id: 'Login to myregistry.com'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
      [
        '-c',
        'docker login --username=$$REGISTRY_USERNAME --password=$$REGISTRY_PASSWORD myregistry.com',
      ]
    secretEnv: ['REGISTRY_USERNAME', 'REGISTRY_PASSWORD']

  - name: "gradle:7.6.1-jdk17"
    id: "run unit tests"
    entrypoint: 'gradle'
    args: ["test"]
```

I've also added the following environment variable:

```
        TESTCONTAINERS_HOST_OVERRIDE=host.docker.internal
```

I receive the following errors when I try to run these tests, though:

```
Step #1 - "run unit tests":     java.lang.IllegalStateException at RyukResourceReaper.java:132
```

Has anyone seen an issue like this before? Is it possible to run Testcontainers in Cloud Build, or will it fail because it's basically starting a Docker container within another Docker container?

Answer (score 3):

I thought Cloud Build provides a Docker environemnt by default. I tried building my sample project here: https://github.com/shelajev/testcontainers-java-spring-boot-quickstart/tree/main

And this is my cloud build yaml:

```
steps:
  - name: 'maven:3-openjdk-18-slim'
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
        mvn test
    dir: '${_APP_NAME}'
    entrypoint: bash
```

And it works correctly out of the box, here is [the build logs](https://ff2d1c85108dfc5a0b702499e28cea1e41577088c7fdc2c0345766c-apidata.googleusercontent.com/download/storage/v1/b/411343891013.cloudbuild-logs.googleusercontent.com/o/log-c688e809-ea79-4319-ae42-a9715b76a48b.txt?jk=AYvHSRFkaBm0Z5Hu-SZBxxXTXLMX7fUDY9OirPgr2QErModSf_o9FiBYPnzH6hD6B7ChLCpOyzkqSC2IlmFerMhTx_8ORjeZbY6NnQw08iWMpQLjJ-hYsUpMP-DFt-fDUN9DeH3qFhNWxOompLmMokO9m9PlwrFcFmnqRD8nKau9QyZdc9pazYQPhkgJw0AwE8qPmZNtQCpMerV8hjUsYdBMJ5W_Oc4Zuwz5oJ2J6-cmieUWyxQHGCKbp8TVWbAVM67XlfvWs_V32QgxT5We1l4VzedqThTvfPaWBd5aYSNqRh36qgnHrhammJXloB8te8LMUOpBWS1UbPdtkg_ukZA4tD5TFT803q36g6Ek1yzdFmNIkYePXM05OZw1vjJC9oQHC2vu7U2vHt2GYuqGYttxiOMSTYrtnqYKExwFx95647G87SVK2V_g5b0B-c-tP5nmhqxHc95tomFbonMjNzq9C-Act9XNVxqr6OA-mywiA4nCryfdVa6yxMveBhxG_XjwbfE7wmzmEudYK4xVYEa6cRq9ZHifY4nG8sz1fT4bVB27M0A30QE1kd5Ca4m5XDpJKwPTFhk9mCj29S3XvBzHgCgaX_8m-KAn-2G6RzKoq-6TojqxJwYU_rrYu5xwagXplBVLN8Noab66R_RvqWSz8DUiTMJkIJ_Q0fKis9IgGX43w0E4_RyI2z09PlJdl8g4J8xvXTJ_WTzrcxbp0e9H8jlq5F7_K7L1pxLET7nbQsbuwP8QxhO1sv1bNL93XuR83CvXZEmqgW4x_Jn0pc1BywfEomWfCh9aMp2u2u6vjPZ0XHYxYjfajo0dQSBKGbu8CX3SxaX1mUTJ9IdIScVq86FYEHYHhDfa8AEdqYGWWyJS4cz7XKN-XLLw3Rjp2ZqaW2IKi7Zs4sO_LO7BkjdzmwX_hvHi0Xl_xSHpvlBwX9RwoubOvoV6L15XzIDmHlnCyXY43xNLqOvz9U9CJIVOnd6g3OJqXN3m38ZDYN3KLcLcUVigxbHMjwF417ft_s6Ukv0ScZnjk4vc48rY6n1-70NDcW-z1QVxiboS4XBdhRfAyOKfGYN3umHeRy9D2UrIqePT0aRqvnoupfp_rbAPEtHi6S8u4lIFvb2R1uhqX-38bWNm_2K_1HjgbjrLzNTTLRzqxXLKNFjVhv3iBvSdcpqERqFSryum09k-VEbttqRAZiiLZySBTHmyrYdQwHMgEaJMo_ycL_CyLajqVkKfOlFrDHFBB9ZaYShyIrFw9b-GuGE&isca=1).

One thing to note, I reckon most of the data is discarded between the steps (unless in `/workspace` -- [docs](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/pass-data-between-steps)) so maybe Docker login doesn't transfer to the gradle step? Can you try maybe a bash entrypoint and running login and gradle check in the same Cloud build step?

Comment: Alright, just got it working: the problem was that the docker config file created from the login step isn't where Testcontainer expects it to be - it's in here on Cloud Build: /builder/home/.docker/config.json. I had to set the DOCKER_CONFIG environment variable to /builder/home/.docker (crucially NOT /builder/home/.docker/config.json) to get this to work. So you're right, the config created by the docker login didn't naturally carry over to the gradle step.

Comment: ooh, perfect! Glad you resolved this!

Comment: A gotcha I faced in a build I was testing was that `build.gradle` had an explicit test checking for the presence of a running docker daemon, which runs fine on laptop/VM, but failed in Cloud Build. The check was modified to check for docker daemon only for environments other than Cloud Build, and that fixed the issue.